# NLog global setup of properties

Tags: logging, nlog

I want to globally setup Logger (NLog) to use it with dependency injection later on with all settings.

I added 2 properties using built-in WithProperty(key, value) method. The problem is that after injecting logger to a class (whether it is an ILogger or Logger.GetLogger or GetCurrentClassLogger it's cleaned up every time (method itself creates new instance of logger so it's understandable).

Do you have any idea how to do this?
I just want to setup properties and after injection use this property without adding WithProperty everytime I want to log something (it would be ok if there is something built-in without custom classes or methods)
I checked solution from one of the stack questions but if I make use it as layoutrenderer then it's not visible in Azure App Insights Custom Properties

I tried all results from stackoverflow and documentation and I found nothing